# Envio de dados para um cliente UDP

Tags: node.js, socket, websocket, cliente-servidor, udp

Eu gostaria de saber se tem como eu enviar dados para um cliente udp em nodejs atraves de um navegador. Eu tenho um form com 2 campos quaisquer, eu preciso pegar esses dados colocados no form e enviar para o cliente udp, eu não sei direito como fazer isso, no meu cliente eu tenho algo como isso:

```
client.on("listening", () => {
  const address = client.address();
  console.log(`server listening ${address.address}:${address.port}`);
});
```

Ele fica ouvindo em uma porta aleatoria, eu só queria pegar os dados do form e entregar pra esse cara. o meu html fica na maquina, não tem servidor http nenhum, é no `/user/desktop/name/index.hml` mesmo

Comment: cliente udp ? tem certeza ? pelo código que você postou parece ser um servidor...e tem certeza que é udp que você quer mesmo ? por que udp ? não tem como usar udp no browser...a configuração que faz mais sentido é um servidor websocket em node.js, e aí sim, fica bem fácil o browser se comunicar com esse servidor

Comment: Eu acabei pegando o código errado, peguei o código do servidor udp, mas esse trecho de código serve tanto pro servidor como pro cliente, essa nomenclatura é só pra diferenciar, ambos os lados o código é muito parecido. e sim, tenho certeza, é um trabalho para faculdade, e tenho que usar o UDP, se fosse com websocket usando o tcp eu já teria terminado, o meu problema é que não sei como posso fazer uma comunicação do  browser com qualquer coisa que seja pelo protocolo udp.

Comment: Eu até cheguei a criar um socket tcp e fiz o navegador enviar dados para ele, mas o problema é que é um socket por tcp né, e eu preciso usar um socket udp. Pelo que eu andei pesquisando o navegador só implementa comunicação tcp. você não teria uma alternativa pra isso ? alguma ideia ?

Comment: de acordo com [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307161/browser-as-udp-dgram-client) pergunta feita no SO inglês, **não é possível** usar UDP no browser...quem pediu o exercício não sabe do que está falando, ou então você não entendeu o que foi pedido

Comment: Não era uma especificação do trabalho, eu estava procurando por conta própria, a inclusão do navegador não era necessária. Mas ok, vlw pela ajuda